# Form onsubmit function restrain the form input value to be passed to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

Sorry in advance if this question has duplicates elsewhere. I have searched for many possible relevant references but just could not get a solution to fix the problem I faced.

I'm having a simple form in jsp which when the user click submit, it will generate an excel for user to download. The form code is as below:-

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" action="MyServlet" method="POST"  onsubmit="startDownload(this)">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2" for="userText">User Text:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userText" name="userText" placeholder="Enter Text">
             </div>
      </div>            
      <div class="form-group"> 
           <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5">
                <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Generate File </button>                        
           </div>
       </div>
  </form>
```

During Form submit, the jsp page will show an loader and when the page prompts for file download it will hide the loader. I'm able to realize this, with reference to this post: [Reenable a form submit button on response of a file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163541/reenable-a-form-submit-button-on-response-of-a-file-download). The onSubmit JavaScript function is as followed:-

```
function startDownload(form) {

            var token = new Date().getTime();
            form.token.value = token;
            showLoading(); //to show the loader 


            var pollDownload = setInterval(function() {
                if (document.cookie.indexOf("download=" + token) > -1) {
                    document.cookie = "download=" + token + "; expires=" + new Date(0).toGMTString() + "; path=/";
                    stopLoading(); //to hide the loader
                    clearInterval(pollDownload);
                }
            }, 500);
}
```

The problem is when I enter some values in the input field form and clicked submit, the value is not passed to the servlet. When I use debugging to check on the variable, it gives 'null'. The code I use to get the form input in servlet :-

```
String userText = request.getParameter("userText");
```

But if I removed the onsubmit function, the value can be passed to servlet.

May I know why is this so and where am I doing wrong in the codes ?

Thank you so much for your kind help and time in advanced!

Comment: Can you check on your browsers Developer Tools (hit F12) Network tab and see if the userText parameter is getting passed?

Comment: @Yserbius Hi, thank you for your reply. As I check, only the token value is getting passed.